# OpenLdap - restore backup - slapcat/slapadd

Tags: backup, ldap, openldap

Im using slapcat to make backup like this:

```
slapcat -n 1 > ${BACKUP_PATH}/ldap.domain.com.ldif
```

Then import using slapadd:

```
slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 1 -l ldap.domain.com.ldif
```

I can't restore my backup this way because of the operational attributes.

I have errors for example:

```
structuralObjectClass: no user modification allowed
```

It's possible to make a backup without operational attributes or import somehow with them?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200504/msg00195.html

You are not allowed to change these as they are internal.

Either remove them from your LDIF or use the `-c` switch (dangerous).

```
slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 1 -c -l ldap.domain.com.ldif
```

As for not writing them in the first place, pipe the output through egrep to trim them:

```
slapcat -n 1 | egrep -v  "^(structuralObjectClass|entryUUID|creatorsName|modifiersName|createTimestamp|modifyTimestamp|entryCSN):" > ${BACKUP_PATH}/ldap.domain.com.ldif
```

From http://vaab.blog.kal.fr/2010/03/10/import-export-ldap-database/

I consider this a bug in `slapcat`, at the very least, it should have an option to 'not' output this stuff.